# icon <i> tags are overlapping on table column

Tags: html, css, jsp, font-awesome

I have a table which has a fixed positioned first column and fixed positioned first row. Now table body has some icon tags which uses font awesome svg images. Now when I am scrolling  right, the icons get overlapped on the first column values. I want them to hidden while scrolling.

Table looks like below without scroll:

[image]

After scroll to right:
[image]

These icons are getting overlapped on left column.

Html table body code:

```
<tbody>
    <c:forEach var="featureSet" items="${featureMatrix}" varStatus="featureIndex">
        <c:choose>
            <c:when test="${featureIndex.index > 0}">
                <tr class="features">
                    <c:forEach var="val" items="${featureSet}" varStatus="customerIndex">
                        <c:set var="formattedVer" value="${fn:replace(featureMatrix[0][customerIndex.index], newLineChar, ' ')}" />
                        <c:set var="custVer" value="${fn:split(formattedVer, ' ')}" />
                        <c:set var="formattedCust" value="${custVer[0]}"/>
                        <c:choose>
                            <c:when test="${customerIndex.index == 0}">
                                <td class="headcol" style="color: white;white-space:nowrap;overflow:auto;">${val}</td>
                            </c:when>
                            <c:otherwise>
                                <c:choose>
                                    <c:when test="${val == '0'}">
                                        <td class="feature" customer-name="${custVer[0]}" feature-name="${featureMatrix[featureIndex.index][0]}">
                                            <a title="Works" href="/feature?customer=${custVer[0]}&version=${custVer[1]}&pfeature=${featureMatrix[featureIndex.index][0]}">
                                                <i style="color:#5aab26" class="fa fa-check-circle fa-lg"></i>
                                            </a>
                                        </td>
                                    </c:when>
                                    <c:when test="${val == '1'}">
                                        <td class="feature" customer-name="${custVer[0]}" feature-name="${featureMatrix[featureIndex.index][0]}">
                                            <a title="Broken" href="/feature?customer=${custVer[0]}&version=${custVer[1]}&pfeature=${featureMatrix[featureIndex.index][0]}">
                                                <i style="color:#f22323" class="fa fa-times-circle fa-lg"></i>
                                            </a>
                                        </td>
                                    </c:when>
                                    <c:when test="${val == '2'}">
                                        <td class="feature" customer-name="${custVer[0]}" feature-name="${featureMatrix[featureIndex.index][0]}">
                                            <a title="Incomplete" href="/feature?customer=${custVer[0]}&version=${custVer[1]}&pfeature=${featureMatrix[featureIndex.index][0]}">
                                                <i style="color:#ffe200" class="fa fa-exclamation-circle fa-lg"></i>
                                            </a>
                                        </td>
                                    </c:when>
                                    <c:when test="${val == '3'}">
                                        <td class="feature" customer-name="${custVer[0]}" feature-name="${featureMatrix[featureIndex.index][0]}">
                                            <a title="Unavailable" href="/feature?customer=${custVer[0]}&version=${custVer[1]}&pfeature=${featureMatrix[featureIndex.index][0]}">
                                                <i class="fa fa-ban fa-lg" style="color:#aaaaaa"></i>
                                            </a>
                                        </td>
                                    </c:when>
                                </c:choose>
                            </c:otherwise>
                        </c:choose>
                    </c:forEach>
                </tr>
            </c:when>
        </c:choose>
    </c:forEach>
</tbody>
```

If I use normal image tags or any other texts, they are hidden while scrolling to right. I have used font awesome icons. How can this overlapping problem be solved for this?

Comment: Do you have output page of the above code?

Comment: thanks but I solved the problem with css z-index in <th> and .headcol